# Fetching newer versions for a given s3 object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an S3 bucket, enabled versioning.

I have also created a schema in my DB in order to capture versions that are already processed for a given file something like below:

```
   s3_data_processing_status
   --------------------------
   file_name: student_id_1.json
   version : xyz
   last_modified_date: 2020-12-28 11:00:06
```

I have a Cron that processes all files created/updated in a given s3 bucket.

To do this, I iterate over the files in the bucket and fetch associated versions. If the associated version for the file is not in the above table, then I process the file.

As I have configured the retention time for each non-current version for a given file object as 30 days, each time I fetch, records for the last 30 days are fetched for a given object.

This is very inefficient as many of the fetched versions for a given object are already processed.

In this context, I found this: [S3 list files newer than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275787/s3-list-files-newer-than).

But I am not getting an idea if is there any way to fetch newer versions for a given s3 object with the condition as

```
  version >= <xyz> OR
  last_modified_date >= <date>
```

Comment: As a first thought - s3 can notify you of any change - send an event to an lambda function, so you don't have to iterate it at all. If the lambda fails you can implement a dead-letter queue and try to process those later.

Comment: Also have you considered to create a lifecycle rule to "Permanently delete previous versions of objects" after 30 days?